# symfony 5 - render collectiontype of FileType without input type file

Tags: php, twig, symfony5

I have one Entity `Hike` with oneTomMany mapped field

```php
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=HikePhotos::class, mappedBy="hikeId", orphanRemoval=true)
 */
 private $hikePhotos;

 public function __construct()
 {
     $this->hikePhotos = new ArrayCollection();
 }
```

And `HikePhotos` entity

```php
/**
  * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Hike::class, inversedBy="hikePhotos")
  * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
  */
private $hikeId;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text")
 */
private $filePath;
```

I render `HikePhotos` in `Hike` form using the `CollectionType`

```php
$builder
->add('hikePhotos', CollectionType::class, [
    'entry_type' => HikePhotosType::class,
    'allow_delete' => true,
    'allow_add' => true,
    'by_reference' => false
]);
```

Generated form contains N html input type file what I want is to list existing photos without input, and only one to add photos.

Actual output

```html
﻿﻿<input type="file" id="hike_hikePhotos_0_filePath" name="hike[hikePhotos][0][filePath]" required="required" class="custom-file-input" lang="fr">
<input type="file" id="hike_hikePhotos_0_filePath" name="hike[hikePhotos][1][filePath]" required="required" class="custom-file-input" lang="fr">
```

Expected something like

```html
<!-- existing photos -->
<span name="hike[hikePhotos][0][filePath]">photo1.jpg</span> <a href="">remove</a>
<span name="hike[hikePhotos][1][filePath]">photo2.jpg</span> <a href="">remove</a>

Add photo
<input type='file'/>
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who're looking for a solution, you have to use `prototype` thanks to [this](http://growingcookies.com/easy-multiple-file-upload-in-symfony-using-the-collectiontype-field/)